# How to update the owner name in custom object based on the mobile no

Tags: triggers, salesforce, workflow, formula

I need to update the owner name based on mobile no present in the custom object.

In the custom object i have the field is called "Referral Id". It's contain the Mobile no,the mobile no already present in user details.In the custom object i need to change the owner name based on the referral id(name).

For example Custom object is created by myself but i put referral id was my manager mobile then it automatically change the lead owner as my manager not me.

I try the following trigger

```
trigger Ownerupdate on Broker__c (before insert,before update) 
{
    //instantiate set to hold unique deployment record ids
    Set<Id> deplomentIds = new Set<Id>();
    for(Broker__c s : Trigger.new)
    {
        deplomentIds.add(s.Referral_ID__c);
    }

    //instantiate map to hold deployment record ids to their corresponding ownerids
    Map<Id, Referral_ID__c> deploymentOwnerMap = new Map<Id, Referral_ID__c>([SELECT Id, Phone FROM User WHERE Id IN: deplomentIds]);

    for (Broker__c s : Trigger.new) 
    {
        if (s.Owner__c == null && deploymentOwnerMap.containsKey(s.Referral_ID__c)) 
        {
            s.Owner__c = deploymentOwnerMap.get(s.Referral_ID__c).OwnerId;
        }
    }
}
```

I got the following Error
    Error: Compile Error: Invalid type: Referral_ID__c at line 11 column 62

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is pretty clear - you are trying to build a map of types `Id` and `Referral_ID__c`. `Referral_ID__c` is not a type, it's the name of the field. The type of the field is probably `String` or `Phone`, whichever one you picked when you created the field.

You also have other issues. For example

```
Set<Id> deplomentIds = new Set<Id>();
    for(Broker__c s : Trigger.new)
    {
        deplomentIds.add(s.Referral_ID__c);
    }
```

is wrong. `deplomentIds` is a set of type `Id`, but you are trying to add mobile phone numbers to it. Phone numbers are not Ids.

What you should do is query for the user that matches their mobile number against your ReferralId and set him as the owner. Something like:

```
for(Broker__c s : Trigger.new)
{
    User owner = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE MobilePhone = :s.Referral_ID__c LIMIT 1];
    s.Owner__c = owner.Id;
}
```

This assumes that there's guaranteed to be one user with that exact mobile number. How you deal with referrals that can't be found, or multiple users matching the referral, is up to you.